# PGF for the Type I Negative binomial Distribution (Problem in Series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, statistics

I was trying to prove the Probability Generating Function for the Type I Negative binomial Distribution.

My attempt,

Let $P(\text{failure})=1-p=q$

$$P(X=x)=\binom{x-1}{k-1}p^kq^{x-k}\space ,x=k,k+1,k+2,...$$

$$G_{x}(t)=\sum_{x=k}^{\infty}\binom{x-1}{k-1}t^xp^kq^{x-k}$$

I was stuck at here. So I tried to look it online and I got the next step which is

$$=(pt)^k\sum_{x=k}^{\infty}\binom{x-1}{k-1}(qt)^{x-k}$$

Can someone explain it to me how my last step to become the step I found online? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: multiply and divide by $t^k$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I got it. Thanks a lot!